# Не применяются HTML тэги к надписи на кнопке в android

Tags: android

Хотелось бы использовать `HTML`-тэги в названии кнопки. А они не применяются.

Что я делаю не так и можно ли обойти проблему?

Добавление текста с тэгами в style.xml тоже не помогает.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/bParams"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button_params_selector"
        android:text="@string/bparams_caption"
        android:onClick="OnButtonParamsClick"
        style="@style/SpeshButtonsFont"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
/>
```

strings.xml:

```
 <string name="bparams_caption">
    дополнительные
  <big>параметры</big>
</string>
```

style.xml:

```
 <style name="SpeshButtonsFont" >
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#f2000700</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) (пункт `Styling with HTML markup`)

> Supported HTML elements include:
>
> - <b> for bold text.
> - <i> for italic text.
> - <u> for underline text.

На этом список допустимых `HTML`-тэгов в `string.xml` заканчивается)

**UPD**

Попробовал всю эту кухню на старой доброй Eclipse, вот результат(на превью в IDE кстати не отображается, только на устройстве):

[image: скрин]

Comment: На самом деле список более обширный. См. мой ответ.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, конечно Ваш вариант приемлем в связке с `Html.fromHtml`, в своем ответе я имел ввиду тэги по дефолту

Comment: Ну, я лично без `Html.fromHtml` не пробовал, но по ссылке в моём ответе больше тегов доступных без использования `Html.fromHtml`

Comment: @ermak0ff, эти тэги тоже не применяются.

Comment: @Bolonat да что Вы говорите, покажите в таком случае как применяли

Comment: Как мне еще показать кроме того, что я написала? Запускаю программу, смотрю на планшет... В дизайнере тоже самое...

Comment: @Bolonat ну в данный момент видно что Вы применяете тэг `<big>` замените его к примеру на `<u>` и посмотрите появится ли результат, да и еще как вариант убрать `style="@style/SpeshButtonsFont"` из разметки

Comment: Проверила на вновь добавленной, "чистой" кнопке. Тэги <u>, </u> к названию не применяются.

Comment: @Bolonat см. UPD

Comment: @ermak0ff, очень интересно...

Comment: @ermak0ff, вообще говоря, такого же эффекта можно добиться и в android studio, если к кнопке применить определенный стиль, в котором указать bold, например. Но мне нужно было только одно слово в названии кнопки выделить, а не все название, поэтому я  хотела применить тэги.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отобразить `HTML` в `TextView` надо пользовать `Html.fromHtml(String html)` таким образом:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

При этом надо иметь в виду, что поддерживаются не все теги. Вот их [список](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754076/which-html-tags-are-supported-by-android-textview):

```
<a> (supports attribute "href")
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div>
<em>
<font> (supports attributes "color" and "face")
<i>
<img> (supports attribute "src". Note: you have to include an ImageGetter to handle retrieving a Drawable for this tag)
<p>
<small>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

**UPD_0:**

Также попробуйте в строковых ресурсах окружить текст вот этим `<![CDATA[`, `]]>`  вот так:

```
<string name="used_libs_list_title"><![CDATA[<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>]]></string>
```

Comment: В TextView у меня все тэги применяются. Вопрос был о применении к свойству Text у Button и не в коде, а в разметке.

Comment: См. обновлённый ответ

Comment: Вставила в strings.xml вашу строку целиком, как есть. На кнопке вывелось <h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>