# Где можно посмотреть какие html теги поддерживает android

Tags: java, android

данный код работает без проблем

```
        String text2 = new StringBuilder()
            .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
            .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
            .toString();

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name) + ": " + getString(R.string.task_list) + " " + title);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(text2));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.send_email)));
```

но если изменить html код text2 на

```
      String text2 = new StringBuilder()
            .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
            .append("<table border=\"1\">\n" +
                    "   <caption>Title</caption>\n" +
                    "   <tr>\n" +
                    "    <th>1 column</th>\n" +
                    "    <th>2 column</th>\n" +
                    "   </tr>\n" +
                    "   <tr><td>text1</td><td>text2</td></tr>\n" +
                    "   <tr><td>text1</td><td>text2</td></tr>\n" +
                    "  </table>")
            .toString();
```

то html форматирование не работает, может быть проблема в самом теге или нет?

Comment: `\n` уберите для начала, если нужен перенос используйте `<br>`

Comment: это Android Studio автоматически добавила

Comment: Вот [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/463753/17609) в моём ответе есть ссылка на список поддерживаемых тэгов и сам их список:

Comment: да нет этого тега в списке(, не подскажите чем можно заменить его? ну или как в виде таблицы вывести нужный текст

Comment: вот, только нашел [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154790) еще объяснение этой проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если мне память не изменяет, то gmail клиент на Android не поддерживает тег `table`.

Да и те же `TextView`/`EditText` тоже `table` не поддерживают.

Comment: да, уже понял, спасибо