# Как реализовать такой вид отправляемого письма?

Tags: java, android

имеется функция `sendTasks`, которая собирает всю информацию о задаче и в итоге формирует данную строку

```
text += Integer.toString(i + 1) + ". " + tasks.get(i).getText() + ": " + DateTimesHelper.makeDateJson(tasks.get(i).getDateOfTask()) + "/ " +
                    DateTimesHelper.makeTime(tasks.get(i).getTime())
                    + contactText + "\r\n\n";
```

потом я передаю этот в `emailIntent`, вот сама реализация

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name) + ": " + getString(R.string.task_list) + " " + title);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.send_email)));
```

полученное письмо на почту получается такого вида
[image: first]

а хочется сделать более аккуратно и читабельно, например так
[image: second]

подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать, пытался применить тег `table`и передать его в `emailIntent` как

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(text));
```

но как выяснилось что тег `table` не поддерживается в android, как можно это решить по другому подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В самом простом(и не лучшем) случае вы можете использовать компонент WebView для отображения html

Cам html формировать каждый раз и отдавать в WebView

```
StringBuilder htmlEmail = new StringBuilder();
htmlEmail.append("<html>").
    append("<body>").
    append("<table border=\"0\"><tr><td>" + string + "</td</tr>/table>").
    append("</body>").
    append("</html>");
mWebView.loadData(str, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: а потом то что получилось в WebView можно передать в emailIntent и отправить письмо?

Comment: WebView просто отображает произвольную страничку(html). Насколько я помню html код(кроме некоторых специфических его частей) чудесно отображается в большинстве клиентов.

Comment: не получается передать в emailIntent WebView, emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mWebView); т.к. нужно передать строку

Comment: emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, htmlEmail); WebView используется для отображения в приложении(это тоже самое что открыть маленький браузер в приложении). В интент нужно передать строку(htmlEmail). И дальше этот текст куда то отправиться. И когда его откроют в каком то клиенте - увидят то что вам нужно и то же, что вы увидите передав htmlEmail в webView

Comment: `htmlEmail`  не получится передать так как тег `table` не работает в android, вот [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484311) посмотрите

Comment: как можно еще можно это реализовать без данного тега?

Comment: Так. Во первых, уж не знаю в какие бородатые года клиент gmail не поддерживал table, но сейчас он все чудесно поддерживает. Если передавать в теле письма валидный html - все отображается. Во вторых - где именно вам нужно отображение этого письма? Если в приложении - используйте webview. Если в почтовых клиентах - формируете валидный html и отправляете. Все

Comment: мне нужно отправить письмо на любой адрес к примеру example@gmail.com и чтоб при открытии этого письма на компьютере было нормально отформатированное письмо как на втором скрине который я выложил к вопросу

Comment: и что значит валидный html?

Comment: Вся проблема в оборачивании/удалении тегов. И в письме получается не html а просто текст между двух тегов. И естественно парсер не знает как его обработать. В конечном итоге простых решений два -  добавить html как вложение к письму, либо использовать кастомную либу. http://habrahabr.ru/post/112450/  https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/

Comment: понял, спасибо за помощь